How to Create Animated FlatList with Sticky Tabs in React Native
Hi everyone,
I'm working on a React Native project and trying to create a component with an animated FlatList that has sticky tabs, similar to what I've seen on PalmPay's data page. I have a screen recording of the exact feature I'm looking to replicate, where tabs remain sticky as the user scrolls through different sections.
Could anyone guide me on how to achieve this? If there's an existing package or best practice for handling this sort of animation and sticky behavior in React Native, I would really appreciate your advice. Here’s what I’m working with:
Using React Native with Expo
Tabs should remain sticky at the top as you scroll through content
Need smooth animations between switching tabs.
Thanks in advance for your help!
I’ve looked into libraries like react-native-tab-view but not working as expected I’m open to any suggestions

try stickyHeader on ScrollView component

I tried using stickyHeader on the ScrollView component, but unfortunately, it didn’t work as expected for my case. Additionally, when I try to wrap a FlatList inside a ScrollView, I’m getting a warning about visualization issues, specifically related to performance and rendering conflicts.
Do you have any ideas on how to handle this with FlatList directly, or perhaps a different approach to keeping the tabs sticky while still using smooth scrolling with animations?

You could check this out: https://www.ifelsething.com/post/how-to-add-a-sticky-header-in-scrollview-react-native/#google_vignette , otherwise, mostly we won't use scrollview in the same time as flatList since both can scroll and will have visualization issues, I recommend to use data.map() instead to render list of data
